# Python / processing - how to mouseClick and change colour within distance of ellipse

Tags: python, python-3.x, processing

Trying to change each circle from one color to another (when clicked within the circles distance). Problem in this code is all circles change to same color. Only want one circle to change when mouse clicks on it. May need to use `dist()` function, however don't know how to implement it.

```py
x = 100
y = 50
circle_x = 50
circle_y = 50
radius= 25
value = 255

def setup ():
    size(400, 400)

def draw (): 
    fill (value, value, 0)
    ellipse (100, y, circle_x, circle_y)
    ellipse (200, y, circle_x, circle_y)
    ellipse (300, y, circle_x, circle_y)

def inside_circle(x, y, circle_x, circle_y, radius):
    if ((x-circle_x)*(x-circle_x) + (y-circle_y)*(y-circle_y)) <= radius*radius:
        return True 
    else:
        return False

def mouseClicked ():
    global x, y, value
    if inside_circle (50, 50, 50, 50, radius):
        fill (0)
    if (value == 255): 
        value = 0
```

Comment: Can you post a more complete solution including imports so it's clear what packages you are using?

Comment: @TimothyJannace Its tagged [*processing*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/processing), so all you need is [Processing 3](https://processing.org/).

Comment: Looks like someone was able to answer so please forgive my mistake. I didn't realize "processing" was a package. :I